# Ubuntu 22.04 - (Finally) moving to netplan, but how?

Tags: networking, netplan

I just migrated a machine to Ubuntu 22.04. Network config is still via /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
# iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.105
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.104
    dns-search example.com
    dns-domain example.com
```

The problem is, after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04, DNS resolving isn't working anymore. No DNS names are resolved.

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search DOMAINS
```

Output of resolvectl:

```
# resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: foreign
      DNS Domain: DOMAINS

Link 2 (eth0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    DNS Domain: DOMAINS
```

I tried to fix this by creating a new netplan config in /etc/netplan and removing /etc/network/interfaces, but this leaves me without a working network config at all (even though netplan is installed).

So how can I enable netplan and /etc/network/interfaces, please? (Hoping that this will fix whatever goes wrong with the current network configuration - but moving to the currently preferred package shouldn't be a big problem in any case, I guess.)

FYI, the yaml I created for netplan, but that doesn't help with name resolving:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.117/24]
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        search: [example.com]
        addresses: [192.168.1.100,192.168.1.104]
  version: 2
```

edit: If I change the netplan config to dhcp, network is working. I'd still like to know how I can get this updated system into a state where netplan works with static addresses. I have no problems with netplan static addresses in fresh installs of Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: If you remove your network config and reboot the system without netplan or `/etc/network/interfaces` and then run `ip link list` what name is provided for your device's ethernet?  Chances are predictive interface names aren't on so `ens18` isn't actually how the system *sees* the device name (`eth0` in the old way) so you might need to check that first.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the gateway.
You must have something like that:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.117/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        search: [example.com]
        addresses: [192.168.1.100,192.168.1.104]
  version: 2
```

Comment: „gateway4“ is deprecated. The new syntax is what you see in my example above as „routes“. Actually, netplan complains if you still use „gateway4“.

Comment: As ThinkHard states, this answer is factually wrong. Netplan moved away from the `gateway4` property, and instead use the `routes` property.